# Make customizer controls get custom setting type value

Tags: theme-customizer, options

I've registered a custom setting type to set a `site_option` rather than `option` or `theme_mod`.

I've written the appropriate action hooks to make these values save and preview properly, and can easily get them in my theme with `get_site_option`.

However, I feel I am missing something obvious, because my *controls* cannot fetch these values. Every time I open the customizer, the defaults are back.

It seems like since there is a `customize_update_{$setting_type}` action, there should be a `customize_get_{$setting_type}` action as well, but there isn't.

[The docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#custom-setting-types) seem to only cover saving and previewing custom setting types, nothing about getting their values.

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

So far the only solution I've been able to discover is to write individual `customize_value_{$setting_id}` filters for each and every setting I add. I hope someone knows of a better way.

Comment: There is a Trac ticket (with several duplicates) for this that pre-dates your question. The last action was a year ago, marking it low priority. Perhaps you should make a comment on it, or submit a patch.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29316
Although, the more I look at your question, the more I think you just need to make sure you supplied a render_content function and a json function, so that the control has what it needs.